# Xamarin Android Binding runtime error: "Could not load type ISecondInterfaceEventsInvoker from assembly"

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

Due the Xamarin ACW bug
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19740

with Xamarin staff i was able to compile and build my Android Binding Project (using a java source file to make a "bridge" between java interfaces).
But now i get this runtime error when i call my class which implements interface.

"Could not load type 'BindingProject.ISecondInterfaceEventsInvoker, BindingProject' from assembly ''."

Do i miss some settings to my Binding Library Assemblies?
Here this my demo project
http://cloud.aliaslab.net/public.php?service=files&t=dfffe4f7a6357e975fce8ef752e78ba4

Thank you for any suggestions!

Lewix

Comment: Ok issue fixed following workaround here
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19740

and check android binding project namespace has to be different from original jar library (i had the same name "com.ingenico.export" in both parts), so project didn't know where to refer "ISecondInterface" implementation class.

Thank you for your help Brendan!

Lewix